# Retrieving process statistics from mdmp file

Tags: windows, winapi, mfc, windbg, memory-dump

What are the WinDbg commands for retrieving information on process statistics like

- number of handles,
- number of threads,
- memory consumption,
- CPU consumption,
- etc.

from memory dump files of type `.mdmp`?

Comment: is that an usermode minidup or kernelmode minidump if it is kernelmode minidump try !process 0 0  user mode minidump contains only stack and reister of a specific process that crashed in general minidumps are useless for deep digging

Comment: Usermode minidump.this minidump is specific to a application crash.

Comment: you can run ~* to find the threads  !handle 0 for a list of handles (if the minidump doesn't contain handle data you are out of luck ) for stack traces of all threads chain ~* with kb like ~*kb

Comment: Be aware: `kb` is misleading on x64

Answer (score 1):

```
load the dump in windbg.
1.) ~* - gives all the threads in loaded process and their stacks.
2.) !runaway - gives execution time for individual threads
3.) !handle - lists all the handles of the application
```

If it is a full memory dump, you can get memory and heap information using:

```
1.) !address <>
2.) !heap
```

once you get the address, you need to dump individual address/blocks to view memory information.

memory consumption and cpu consumption counters are not part of mini dumps.
information in #1 should be good enough to give you an idea of offending call that leads to crash.

Comment: // 0  Id: b30.a80 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ffdf000 Unfrozen
      Start: MyApp+0x33d0f (00433d0f) 
      Priority: 0  Priority class: 32  Affinity: f  // can you help me in decoding this information,how do i find the actual thread name.

Comment: if you use Visual Studio, turn off optimization, recompile. That should build with pdb's which will make the dumps more useful

Comment: `~*` does not show the stacks. Did you mean `~*k` to show the stacks? That again may be too verbose for an overview. You may want `!runaway 7` for more details. Use `!address -summary` for an overview. The command `!address <>` as written fails with an error message. For heap statistics, `!heap -s` may be better suited to get a first overview. Another command I regularly use: `.time`